# A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_core'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am experiencing this problem when building the mobile / android flutter app, kindly help:

```
[ +271 ms] > Configure project :firebase_core
[        ] Evaluating project ':firebase_core' using build file 'C:\Users\kelsey\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_core-2.4.0\android\build.gradle'.
[        ] Using default execution profile
[        ] Could not execute [class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.KotlinBuildStatHandler.buildFinished]
[   +2 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +3 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_core'.
[   +1 ms] > com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: defaultConfig contains custom BuildConfig fields, but the feature is disabled.
[   +1 ms] * Try:
[   +4 ms] > Run with --debug option to get more log output.
[   +1 ms] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Exception is:
[        ] org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_core'.

[        ] Caused by: com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: defaultConfig contains custom BuildConfig fields, but the feature is disabled.
[        ]  at com.android.builder.errors.IssueReporter.reportError(IssueReporter.kt:113)
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of `firebase_core` ?

Comment: yes it is the latest version: 2.4.0

Comment: Your below answer resolved my issue, but now I get the 

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file
android {
    namespace 'com.example.namespace'
}

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think this issue is due to the deprecation of [buildConfigField](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/370c706fb6553dc5952e10323a81f2b195405c3f%5E%21/) (from android.packageBuildConfig).

Try adding the following line to `gradle.properties`:

```
android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true
```

Also, note that this is a temporary solution until the `firebase_core` package resolves the issue.

Comment: This resolved my issue, but now I get the following issue:

 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file android { namespace 'com.example.namespace' }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74763607/a-problem-occurred-configuring-project-firebase-core

Comment: @JosephWambura I hope you resolved your issue, as I'm seeing your answer in the link you provided.

Comment: Yes I used the provided answer.