# A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_core'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am experiencing this problem when building the mobile / android flutter app, kindly help. An issue with the namespace being required, but not present on the firebase_core library. How can I disable the IDE not to validate the [namespace of a library](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace)?:

```
[        ] Using default execution profile
[        ] Could not execute [class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.statistics.KotlinBuildStatHandler.buildFinished]
[   +4 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +4 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_core'.
[        ] > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
[        ]    > Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:
[        ]      android {
[        ]          namespace 'com.example.namespace'
[        ]      }
[        ]      If the package attribute is specified in the source AndroidManifest.xml, it can be migrated automatically to the namespace value in the build.gradle file using the AGP Upgrade Assistant; please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.
[        ] * Try:
[        ] > Run with --debug option to get more log output.
[        ] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[   +1 ms] * Exception is:
[        ] org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_core'
```

Comment: How can I disable https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace

Answer (score 2):

Downgraded to use this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
```

as shown below: [flutterfire issue 10094](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10094)